# How to highlight the current menu item in php

Tags: php, html, css

This is a part of header.php file. If i make a menu nav in header.php and i included it in every page on my website, how do i go about highlighting the current page if all i can put on the page is include("header.php"); Please Help me out from this problem.

Thanks and Regards

```
<div class="form-inline" id="myDIV">
       <ul class="social-icons">
        <li class="new-link"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li class="new-link"><a href="#">About Us</a></li> 
        <li class="new-link"><a href="#">Parties</a></li> 
        <li class="new-link"><a href="#">Candidates</a></li>
        <li class="new-link"><a href="#">News</a></li>
        <li class="new-link"><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
        <li class="sign-in new-link"><a href="#">Login </a></li>
        <span> / </span>
        <li class="new-link"><a href="#"> Register</a></li>
      </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Did you try something before asking? What issues are you facing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

**home.php**

```
$home_active = 'active';
```

**about.php**

```
$about_active = 'active';
```

**parties.php**

```
$parties_active = 'active';
```

Menu:

```
<div class="form-inline" id="myDIV">
       <ul class="social-icons">
        <li class="new-link <?php echo $home_active ?>"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li class="new-link <?php echo $about_active ?>"><a href="#">About Us</a></li> 
        <li class="new-link <?php echo $parties_active ?>"><a href="#">Parties</a></li> 
      </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add below `if` condtion in every `<li>` tag

```
<li class="new-link <?php if($args[2] == 'home.php') { echo "active"; } ?> " >
    <a href="home.php">Home</a>
</li>
```

Comment: still, cause an issue, it will add like : class="new-link 'class="active"' "

Comment: Yes now it same like my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

get current script name :

```
$active_page = basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);
```

Update your menu item for active page:

```
<li class="new-link <?php if( $active_page == 'home.php') {?> active <?php  } ?> "   ><a href="#">Home</a></li>
```

add CSS for `active` class with highlighting effect.